# Angular 2 application running on iis returns not found when reload

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, routes, iis-express

I made a new page in IIS. I connected a physical path to my angular 2 app source.

When I access the page with `localhost:port` I get to the page normally.

When I switch to some other view, e.g. `localhost:port/Employees`, it works ok at first, but when I reload the page it returns an HTTP-404 error for the same URL. Anyone had this problem? I think it has something to do with angular 2 routing.

Also IIS gives this response:

> Most probable causes: The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.

Comment: You're probably going to need to post some code if you want useful answers. I'd suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then editing your question to include the suggestions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with Angular Routing . This is a thing that has to be handled on the server side. When doing a refresh the server should redirect  to the base path.

> By default Angular 2 applications don't use a hash (#) prefix on urls,
>   the effect of this is that if you try to navigate directly to a deep
>   link in your angular app or refresh an internal page you may get a 404
>   page not found error. This is because the web server receiving the
>   request looks for a resource matching the full url on the server,
>   which doesn't exist because the angular portion of the url refers to a
>   route in your angular application and needs to be handled in the
>   client browser.

One work around for this in Angular you can use `HashLocationStrategy` .

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

**Angular 2 + IIS - URL Rewrite Rule to prevent 404 error after page refresh**

> The way to fix this is by rewriting all virtual urls to the main
>   Angular 2 index.html file.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: But will this kind of configuration always redirect page to main view or to the one I refreshed/reloaded?

Comment: @OjamaYellow it is a work around not a solution ,  as this is a thing that has to be handled by the server configuration . or better use `HashLocationStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

try to set in the `index.html`:

in the `<head></head>` tag:

```
<base href="./" /> or  <base href="/" />
```

And the set in the `webconfig` file your index.html as `default page`

Hope it help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need your server to handle it if you are not using hash in url. Your server need to fallback to inndex.html if the requested page not found. also you nneed

```
<base href="/"/>
```